# MySQL "IS IN" equivalent?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

A while ago I worked on a MS-SQL project and I remember a "IS IN" thing. I tried it on a MySQL project and it did not work.

Is there an equivalent? Workaround?

Here is the full query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_product, product_viewhistory, product_xref
WHERE 
(
(product_viewhistory.productId = product_xref.product_id_1 AND product_xref.product_id_2 = product_product.id)
OR 
(product_viewhistory.productId = product_xref.product_id_2 AND product_xref.product_id_1 = product_product.id)
)
AND product_product.id IS IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT pvh.productId
    FROM product_viewhistory AS pvh
    WHERE pvh.cookieId = :cookieId
    ORDER BY pvh.viewTime DESC
    LIMIT 10)
AND product_viewhistory.cookieId = :cookieId
AND product_product.outofstock='N'
ORDER BY product_xref.hits DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It's pretty big ... but the part I am interested in is:

```
AND product_product.id IS IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT pvh.productId
    FROM product_viewhistory AS pvh
    WHERE pvh.cookieId = :cookieId
    ORDER BY pvh.viewTime DESC
    LIMIT 10)
```

Which basically says I want the products to be in the "top 10" of that sub-query.

How would you achieve that with MySQL (while trying to be efficient)?

Comment: Isn't it the same as 'in' in MySQL?

Comment: IN is what you're looking for, but this should really be implemented using a JOIN instead of a subquery.

Comment: Please advise on the "JOIN". Because anyways mysql doesn't allow "LIMIT" inside "IN". So I might have to do JOIN?

Comment: i think i figured it out, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `IN`:

```
AND product_product.id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT pvh.productId
    FROM product_viewhistory AS pvh
    WHERE pvh.cookieId = :cookieId
    ORDER BY pvh.viewTime DESC
    LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'".
I guess this is another issue ...

Answer (score 2):

Try `IN` (no "is")